# Call method when app comes to foreground, is unlocked, or is accessed via a notification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need my app to call a method any time is is "brought back" from not being in the foreground. I understand that there are several ways to bring an app back to the screen (i.e. clicking on the app icon to bring it back up, clicking the "view" button a notification that comes from the app and pops up on the users home screen, unlocking their device when they had locked it while using the app). I need to call a method in case of any of these circumstances. I also need the method to be called early because something needs to change in the UI depending on the User's location.

I am currently using this to register the method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(appReturnsActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification 
object:nil];
```

And this to call the method:

```
- (void)appReturnsActive{
// code in here
}
```

This does not seem to fire every time. Does anyone know why its not working? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Use the appdelegate's `-applicationWillEnterForeground:` or register to `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`

See apple's Doc's: [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  addObserver:self
  selector:@selector(appReturnsActive)
  name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
  object:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation on that method ***"The method specified by notificationSelector must have one and only one argument (an instance of NSNotification)."***  Put a colon after your method name in the addObserver call, and then add an instance of NSNotification as a parameter in your method...see below....

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(appReturnsActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification 
object:nil];
```

and the method call

```
- (void)appReturnsActive:(NSNotification *)notification{
    // code in here
}
```

Comment: This response is the correct one. `code`-applicationWillEnterForeground:`code` won't be called if you unlock the phone and the app was already on foreground when you locked it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, didn't look at the original question. The code should be working the same way with or without the notification parameter. So this doesn't actually solves the original question.